# VSTO Word Add-In: How to add a content control in a array cell

Tags: c#, vsto

I'm building a VSTO Word Add-In which creates an array upon clicking on it. In one of the array cells I would like to add some text, a new line, and a richtext content control.

I've managed to get it working by using the following code:

```
Word.Table table = Globals.MyAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(currentRange, 8, 3, ref missing, ref missing);
range = table.Cell(1, 3).Range;
range.Text = "SomeText" + Environment.NewLine;
range.MoveStartUntil(Environment.NewLine, Word.WdConstants.wdForward);
range.MoveStart(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1);
range.MoveEnd(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1);
Word.ContentControl cc = range.ContentControls.Add();
cc.Tag = "someTag";
```

I don't understand why the "MoveStart" and "MoveEnd" instructions are required instead of just using the "MoveStartUntil" instruction. Is there a better way to do that?

Also, I would like to add the bold effect on the text I write but not on the text that will be written in the content control field. I've tried adding the following code but it applies on the all cell and not just my text.

```
range.Bold = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are having trouble with newlines. Your best approach in cases like this is to step through the code as it runs and check the value of `Text` at each step (I usually find myself having to do this anyway, just to get things to work).

```
Word.Table table = Globals.MyAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(currentRange, 8, 3, ref missing, ref missing);
range = table.Cell(1, 3).Range;
// The text here starts as "\r\a"; if you turn on paragraph marks you will see an icon in each table cell; this must be that character

range.Text = "SomeText" + Environment.NewLine;
// Now the text is now "SomeText\r\r\a" (NewLine is "\r\n" and I think "\n" gets converted to "\r")
// Note that Word will put \r or \a back if you omit them, since you're in a table cell

range.MoveStartUntil(Environment.NewLine, Word.WdConstants.wdForward);
// Now it's "\r\r\a"

range.MoveStart(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1);
// "\r\a"

range.MoveEnd(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1);
// finally the text is null (because it's a 0-length range), and in the needed location

Word.ContentControl cc = range.ContentControls.Add();
cc.Tag = "someTag";
```

You also want to make the first line bold, but in none of these steps is only the text "SomeText" selected (you need to omit the trailing characters, or anything that is inserted before them will have the specified formatting too), so you'll have to modify it a bit before you can use `range.Bold = 1`.

This is a way you could do it:

```
Range currentRange = Paragraphs[3].Range;
Table table = Tables.Add(currentRange, 8, 3, ref missing, ref missing);
Range range = table.Cell(1, 3).Range;
// Starts as "\r\a"

range.Text = "SomeText";
// The text is now "SomeText\r\a"

range.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1);
// "SomeText"

range.Bold = 1;
range.InsertParagraphAfter();
// "SomeText\r" (this puts the paragraph mark inside the current range which is kind of counter-intuitive)

range.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
// This is the new paragraph

Interop.ContentControl cc = range.ContentControls.Add();
cc.Tag = "someTag";
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you show is on the right track, it's just a matter of how to use the `Range` object. There's certainly more than one way. The code sample below is my preference.

Basically, you want to do three things, so you need to work with the target `Range` three times: text + bold; new paragraph; add the content control.

The key with using a Range, then adding something to it, is to *collapse* the Range. Think of it like pressing the right-arrow key on the keyboard to collapse a selection to a blinking insertion point. The same needs to be done to a Range; you use the `Collapse` method, collapsing to the end point (there's also the option to collapse to the starting point).

Put the text into the Range, then do any formatting required. The paragraph mark is then inserted, after which the Range again needs to be collapsed. Table cells are a special case: when collapsing to the end at the end of a table cell, focus ends up in the next cell. So it's necessary to move back one character.

Then the content control can be added.

```
    object oCollapseEnd = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;
    rng.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);
    Word.Table table = doc.Tables.Add(rng, 8, 3, ref missing, ref missing);
    Word.Range range = table.Cell(1, 3).Range;
    range.Text = "SomeText";
    range.Font.Bold = -1;
    range.InsertAfter(Environment.NewLine);
    range.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);
    range.MoveEnd(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1);
    Word.ContentControl cc = range.ContentControls.Add();
    cc.Tag = "someTag";
```

Comment: The bold effect wasn't applied only on the first line but on all the text, I had to add the range.MoveEnd instruction **before** the Bold effect.